# oracle database home page doesn't show when upgrading apex to 4.2.6 its just the apex home page.. why?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

If you install oracle 11g Express edition you also get apex 4.2. no issues.it works perfectly.. the oracle home page works well.you create your workspace..and  apex log ins works well too .
After you upgrade apex 4.2 to apex 4.2.6. you can log in to your already created workspace but to load the oracle home page to manage your work space it doesn't load anymore.meaning after upgrade you might not be able to create a new workspace

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected. The Express edition has a special "home page" (built in Oracle Apex) which gets removed if you upgrade Apex.

You get a choice: either stick with Express edition and use the home page, or upgrade and lose it.

All the functions of the home page, however, can be done yourself using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer - just not so easily :)

For creating workspaces, however, you do that using the Apex Admin pages. The URL will be something like `http://host/apex/apex_admin`.

Comment: Wow ... Thanks Boss ... atleast av seen an "administrative services page" though its kinda weird .. I cant login with my username and password i gave during installation.. I eally love this response much appreciated

Comment: If you don't know the admin password you can reset it with the apxchpwd.sql script.

Comment: HAHAHAHAH... THANKS BOSS.. AM JUST PARANOID OF GOING BACK TO COMMAND LINE . IVE GOTTEN SO FAR IN LEARNING APEX.. I DON'T WANT ANOTHER ISSUE I HAD LAST TIME ILL WORK WITH THE 2 WORKSPACES I HAVE..THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR REPLY SIR.GOD BLESS

Comment: FORGIVE MY GREED .. JUST 2 MORE QUESTIONS 1. HOW DO YOUR SET YOUR APPLICATION TO HAVE AN ICON OR IMAGE LIKE THE PACKAGED APPS 2. HOW WILL A PAGE HAVE FOUR REGIONS APART FROM THE NAVIGATION ITEMS ON THE SIDE .(LIKE TH  EXAMPLE SAMPLE APPLICATION FIRST PAGE)

Comment: This site is free, just raise new questions. Also, don't use ALL CAPS, it looks like you're shouting.